# how to defer scripts called as $helper->addScript

Tags: jquery-deferred

Could someone tell me if a script called like this can be deferred:

$helper->addScript( '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' );

All of my scripts are called like this in my theme and i would like to defer them as per suggestions to speed up page load.

I've already tried adding defer="defer" but that did not work or i didn't use it correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:

https://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScript

Try this:

$helper->addScript( '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', 'text/javascript', true, false );

Comment: Please embed the essential bits of the off-site resource into your answer.